# Protractor: tracking current spec

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am using protractor and trying to create files with filenames based on a timestamp. The problem is that even though I use browser.sleep() to wait a random amount of time before creating the timestamp (which is used to create the file name), the filenames are still within about 50ms of each other:

```
    if (instanceCount < 4) {
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10000 - 500 + 1)) + 500;
        console.log("instanceCount == " + instanceCount + "... sleeping " + randomNumber + " ms");
        browser.sleep(randomNumber);
    }

    var date = new Date();
    timeStamp = date.getMonth() + 1 + '-' + date.getDate() + '-' + date.getFullYear() + '-' +
        date.getHours() + 'h' + date.getMinutes() + 'm' + date.getSeconds() + 's' + date.getMilliseconds() + 'ms';

    fs.writeFileSync(filepath + timeStamp, 'utf8');

    instanceCount = fs.readdirSync(filepath).length;
```

The timeStamp variable seems to ignore the browser.sleep() function. I tried using a function that returns a promise but could not get that to work either. Here is what I came up with:

```
    var getTimestamp = function() {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

            if (instanceCount < 4) {
                var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10000 - 500 + 1)) + 500;
                console.log("instanceCount == " + instanceCount + "... sleeping " + randomNumber + " seconds");
                browser.sleep(randomNumber);
            }

        });
    };

        getTimestamp().then(function () {
            var date = new Date();
            timeStamp = date.getMonth() + 1 + '-' + date.getDate() + '-' + date.getFullYear() + '-' +
                date.getHours() + 'h' + date.getMinutes() + 'm' + date.getSeconds() + 's' + date.getMilliseconds() + 'ms';

                fs.writeFileSync(filepath + timeStamp, 'utf8');
        },
```

Can someone tell me if I'm on the right track and/or if this makes sense in terms of flow control/execution?

Comment: Instead of trying to write some file with some arbitrary timestamp, there are other ways to get other more meaningful files written.  You could use a jasmine-reporters and use consolidation to false. This will write files by spec. See this https://github.com/angular/protractor-cookbook/blob/master/jasmine-junit-reports/conf.js#L18. You could also separate out using the blocking proxy feature to separate out logs. For more information about blocking proxy, look at the readme file in https://github.com/angular/blocking-proxy.

Comment: I tried using jasmine-reporters but the only method I could get working was the addReporter method, and I already have a reporter logging to my console. I realize naming a file from a timestamp doesn't seem like best practice but the primary functionality I need from this code is to read how many files are in a folder at a given point in time. The file itself doesn't really matter, and having the filename as the timestamp helps show what's going on in the execution. I've updated my question with the instanceCount variable to show what I mean

Comment: Have you tried the cookbook for this? It should separate it out by specs. If all your tests are in one file, this will only produce one file.

Comment: This code does create multiple files, but since the instanceCount variable doesn't wait for the browser.wait() function, sometimes 2 different specs/files read at the same time, and instanceCount has the same value for 2 different specs which is a problem

Comment: I am not sure if the comment above is for your code. It just doesn't sound like a good strategy so I would suggest trying out one of the recommendations. Because nothing in your code above uses browser.wait so I'm not sure what this is referring to.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the browser.sleep() function. It seems like that function carries out executing the code below without waiting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137965/discussion-between-cnishina-and-tom).

Answer (score 0):

Your method needs to resolve a promise if you are going to use a new promise. Also if you are going to use browser.sleep, you need to return that promise. In the example below, I chained it to return a boolean value. This will help us make a decision to write the file or not to write the file.

```
/**
 * gets the timestamp should resolve and return a promise
 * @returns Promise<boolean> if true, it is instanceCount < 4. false
 *          if instanceCount >= 4
 */
let getTimestamp = function() {
  if (instanceCount < 4) {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10000 - 500 + 1)) + 500;
    console.log("instanceCount == " + instanceCount + "... sleeping " + randomNumber + " seconds");
    return browser.sleep(randomNumber).then(() => { return true });
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve(false);
  }
};

getTimestamp().then((result)=> {
  if (result) {
    let date = new Date();
    timeStamp = date.getMonth() + 1 + '-' + date.getDate() + '-' + date.getFullYear() + '-' +
    date.getHours() + 'h' + date.getMinutes() + 'm' + date.getSeconds() + 's' + date.getMilliseconds() + 'ms';
    fs.writeFileSync(filepath + timeStamp, 'utf8');
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with a lot of help from cnishina which involves using the browser.wait()'s .then method and extending it all the way down (about 50 lines) to where I needed the execution to be synchronous. The cool thing is that everything after the end of the .then function executes asynchronously, which means there is actually no time is wasted at all! Here's the code:

```
        browser.sleep(randomNumber).then(function () {

            var date = new Date();
            timeStamp = date.getMonth() + 1 + '-' + date.getDate() + '-' + date.getFullYear() + '-' +
                date.getHours() + 'h' + date.getMinutes() + 'm' + date.getSeconds() + 's' + date.getMilliseconds() + 'ms';

            fs.writeFileSync(filepath + timeStamp, 'utf8');

            //.then function continues...
```